# minwg и opengl freeglut

Tags: opengl, mingw

скачал MinGW-get version 0.6.3
https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/
установил в C:\MinGW, запустил инсталлятор (MinGW Installer) и загрузил компилятор mingw32-gcc-g++-bin 8.2.0-2,
прописал PATH C:\MinGW\bin, откомпилировал hello world работает.

скачал freeglut MinGW (freeglut-MinGW-3.0.0-1.mp.zip)
https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/
из архива: (содержимое папок х64 не трогал)

- содержимое папки include\GL переместил в C:\MinGW\include\GL
- содержимое папки lib переместил в C:\MinGW\lib
- содержимое папки bin переместил в C:\Windows\System32

перезагрузил комп, написал программу

```
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(){
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(0.0,0.1,0.0);

   glBegin(GL_LINES);
       glVertex2f(50,50);
       glVertex2f(100,200);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
   glutCreateWindow ("title");
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluOrtho2D(0,512,0,512);

   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutMainLoop();

};
```

попытался откомпилировать (g++ main.cpp)
вывело:

```
C:\Users\U1\Desktop\project>g++ main.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:     
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `glColor3f@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `glBegin@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `glVertex2f@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `glVertex2f@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `glEnd@0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `glFlush@0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowSize@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity@0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18a): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D@32'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `_imp__glutDisplayFunc@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
C:\Users\U1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjZXej2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `_imp__glutMainLoop@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

что я делаю не так или сделал?

Comment: В вызове `g++` не хватает подключения библиотек флажками `-l...`. (Наверное `g++ main.cpp -lfreeglut -lopengl32`, или как-то так.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ответ надо ввести g++ main.cpp -o example -I"C:\MinGW\include" -L"C:\MinGW\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows